# Not understanding an error code when using the Tkz-Euclide package

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am getting the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
Missing character: There is no I in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ] in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ( in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no O in font nullfont!
./Internal and external with nodes.tex:18: Use of \tkz@DefLine doesn't match it
s definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.18 ...wSegments[add = .5 and .5, new](D,D' E,E')./Internal and external with nodes.tex:18: Argument of \tikz@path@overlayed has
 an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.18 ...wSegments[add = .5 and .5, new](D,D' E,E')
```

when trying to render this diagram, I cannot tell what is wrong as it comes straight from the manual, am I doing something stupid?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/-5/A,3/0/B,5/-5/C}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[int](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[ext](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{J}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = I] (O,B)         \tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = I] (A,C)         \tkzGetPoints{D'}{E'}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = J] (O,B)         \tkzGetPoints{F}{G}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = J] (A,C) 
    \tkzGetPoints{F'}{G'}
    \tkzDrawCircles(O,B A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = .5 and .5, new](D,D' E,E')
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = 0 and 0.25, new](J,F J,G)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,I,J,D,E,F,G,D',E',F',G')
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me understand the error message so I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\tkzSetUpStyle[color=orange,line width=.2pt]{new}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/-5/A,3/0/B,5/-5/C}
\tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[int](O,B)(A,C)   \tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[ext](O,B)(A,C)   \tkzGetPoint{J}
\tkzDefLine[tangent  from=I](O,B)        \tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
\tkzDefLine[tangent from=I](A,C)         \tkzGetPoints{D'}{E'}
\tkzDefLine[tangent from=J](O,B)         \tkzGetPoints{F}{G}
\tkzDefLine[tangent from=J](A,C)         \tkzGetPoints{F'}{G'}
\tkzDrawCircles(O,B A,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[add = .5 and .5,new](D,D' E,E')
\tkzDrawSegments[add = 0 and 0.25](J,F J,G)
\tkzDrawPoints(O,A,I,J,D,E,F,G,D',E',F',G')
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Like Scott wrote no space between `]` and `(`
2. You need to define the style `new`
3. I don't understand the comment about the result because with the version 4.25 (last version) I get the same result as my documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following compiles fine for me (after removing some spaces) and the `new` key which isn't defined in your document.  In particular I removed all the spaces from the

```
\tkzDefLine[tangent from = I] (O,B)
```

commands.  **With that said, the output looks nothing like what's in the documentation so I don't know what's actually going on.**

It took me a while to figure out what `new` was when I first looked through the documentation.  It's defined on p32 as:

```
\tkzSetUpStyle[color=orange,line width=.2pt]{new}
```

so you can add it to your document if you care to.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/-5/A,3/0/B,5/-5/C}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[int](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[ext](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{J}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from=I](O,B)         \tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from=I](A,C)         \tkzGetPoints{D'}{E'}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from=J](O,B)         \tkzGetPoints{F}{G}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from=J](A,C) 
    \tkzGetPoints{F'}{G'}
    \tkzDrawCircles(O,B A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = .5 and .5](D,D' E,E')
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = 0 and 0.25](J,F J,G)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,I,J,D,E,F,G,D',E',F',G')
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but you are right it looks nothing like the manual! will have to play around with it to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @PaulA I'm sure someone will come along and tell you what's actually happening and when they do please accept their answer!

Answer (score 0):

The command `\tkzDefLine` is defined with

```
\def\tkzDefLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DefLine}{\tkz@DefLine[]}}
\def\tkz@DefLine[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
%\pgfkeys{/tkzdefline/.cd,K=1}  
\pgfqkeys{/tkzdefline}{#1}  
\ifcase\tkz@numline%
 % first case 0
 \tkzDefMediatorLine(#2)  
  \or% 1
  \tkzDefOrthLine[\tkz@koeff](#2)
  \or% 2
   \tkzDefLineLL(#2)
  \or% 3
  \tkzDefBisectorLine(#2)
  \or% 4
  \tkzDefBisectorOutLine(#2)
  \or% 5
  \tkzDefSymmedianLine(#2)
    \or% 6
  \tkzDefAltitudeLine(#2)
  \or% 7
   \tkzDefEulerLine(#2)
   \or% 8
   \tkzTgtFromP(#2)(\tkz@ptfrom)
 \or% 9
   \tkzTgtAt(#2)(\tkz@ptat)
  \fi    
\endgroup
}
```

TeX is awaiting for `(` just after `]` in `\tkzDefLine` arguments, and adding a space between them results on an error.

The solution is to change `\tkz@DefLine` command and  add `\pgfutil@ifnextchar(` just after the command to ignores any spaces between `]` and `(`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 

\tikzset{new/.style={color=orange,line width=.2pt}}

\makeatletter

\def\tkzDefLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@DefLine}{\tkz@DefLine[]}}
\def\tkz@DefLine[#1]{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar(%)
    {\tkz@Def@Line{#1}}
    {\ERROR}%
}

\def\tkz@Def@Line#1(#2){% 
\begingroup
%\pgfkeys{/tkzdefline/.cd,K=1}  
\pgfqkeys{/tkzdefline}{#1}  
\ifcase\tkz@numline%
 % first case 0
 \tkzDefMediatorLine(#2)  
  \or% 1
  \tkzDefOrthLine[\tkz@koeff](#2)
  \or% 2
   \tkzDefLineLL(#2)
  \or% 3
  \tkzDefBisectorLine(#2)
  \or% 4
  \tkzDefBisectorOutLine(#2)
  \or% 5
  \tkzDefSymmedianLine(#2)
    \or% 6
  \tkzDefAltitudeLine(#2)
  \or% 7
   \tkzDefEulerLine(#2)
   \or% 8
   \tkzTgtFromP(#2)(\tkz@ptfrom)
 \or% 9
   \tkzTgtAt(#2)(\tkz@ptat)
  \fi    
\endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/-5/A,3/0/B,5/-5/C}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[int](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzDefSimilitudeCenter[ext](O,B)(A,C)  \tkzGetPoint{J}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = I] (O,B)  \tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = I] (A,C)  \tkzGetPoints{D'}{E'}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = J] (O,B)  \tkzGetPoints{F}{G}
    \tkzDefLine[tangent from = J] (A,C)  \tkzGetPoints{F'}{G'}
    \tkzDrawCircles(O,B A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = .5 and .5,new](D,D' E,E')
    \tkzDrawSegments[add = 0 and 0.25,new](J,F J,G)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,I,J,D,E,F,G,D',E',F',G')
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also just do `\def\tkz@DefLine[#1]#2(#3)` and ignore everything between `]` and `(` (with no error detection, of course).